# Cropping PDF to eliminate whitespace

Tags: pdf

I have maths exam question pdfs that have short paragraphs with the question, and solution. There is then a page break and another paragraph of text. Sometimes the solutions fill the page.

I'd like to put all the text onto one page by removing any white space.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

I'm using windows 8.1. A GUI would be appreciated or an easy to follow guide for command line. Also, the solution will need to handle mathematical formulae

Thanks

Comment: Convert it to a Word document, go through and delete the page breaks, then convert back to a PDF document.

Comment: See: [Editing PDF to remove section?](http://superuser.com/q/303923/87805) or [Is there a good stable free PDF editor?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19011/3474)

Comment: @mfashraf You've to specify your OS and what exactly you're looking for. Asking for tools is off-topic.

Comment: @Ramhound I will give that a go! I'm not sure it will handle formulas, but I didn't make that clear in my initial post. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @kenorb I've added more details, is that better? What would be an appropriate tag? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PDF is just a file format to present document, therefore all you need to use [any PDF editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19011/3474) to achieve that. Or use the software which allows you to convert PDF file into RTF/DOC file.

If your file is editable you shouldn't have any problems. However if your file contains a scanned images, then it's more tricky as you've to use OCR program to convert it into editable document first (such as *.rtf*, *.doc*, *.docx*) and convert it to PDF again.

See also:

- [Editing PDF to remove section?](https://superuser.com/questions/303923/editing-pdf-to-remove-section)

Answer (score 0):

One correct method was suggested in the earlier answer but without explaining why.

A PDF generally has little or no "White Space" basically voids are created by offsets between contents, so just the zones intended for inking in a printer. Pages have NO page breaks, as all pages can be stored inside a PDF, in any order, then reassembled into a screen or printer sequence, side to side, down to up or even one above the other, so no physical relationship, as for example pages could even be repeated or nested in the area of other(s).

So to move contents from any page (section) to another, it either needs to be converted into a conventional Word Processing format or edited in a "Re-flowable" PDF editor, that then has "Page Breaks" like HTML or Doc can add when reprinting.

When working with a page that was scanned then image slicing would be required and that is what some PDF reflow software such as https://willus.com/k2pdfopt/ may use. Note the recommendation there is to use MS Word.